Bought new Asus laptop and keyboard locks on install
I bought an Asus laptop today. And I want to dual boot it with ubuntu. Keyboard freezes. So I cannot install. Model is FA507NU

What happens when you attach an external keyboard to your laptop? Can you boot from the USB installer and run an Ubuntu live session after clicking the Try Ubuntu button? What happens when you unplug the external keyboard, and try to run the Ubuntu live session using your laptop's native keyboard?

I dont have one I can use now..I have one with a cable but it is ps2 and i need an adaptor. VMware works

can you get to bios with the keyboard(do not change anything there unless you know what you are doing), with the usb attached what happens when you exit bios?

I will try probably during the weekend. I know older bios versions but the one time i got in that one it looked strange. I also have a wired external keyboard but i need a ps2 to usb adaptor to connect it

Bluetooth was off. That was the issue. All wireless devices are scanned as Bluetooth. I dont know what this had to do. I added an external usb keyboard in windows. It was scanned as Bluetooth. Then I used advanced options to boot. Keyboard was working. Laptop one too
